# setFileAttachments method on MassEmailMessage class available?

Tags: apex, apex-email-service

According to the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_mass.htm), MassEmailMessage class does not have the .setFileAttachments method.

The reason why I'm using MassEmailMessage in the first place is because I cannot use the .setToAddresses method with the [SingleEmailMessage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm), as I am using a templateId. This forced me to abandon using setTargetObjectId and rather adopt setTargetObjectIds.

> Optional. A list of email addresses to which you are sending the email. The maximum number of email addresses allowed is 100. This argument is allowed only when a template is not used.

So I need to leverage the SingleEmailMessage class, because I need to be able to send emails with attachments. However, adopting this approach means I won't be able to email multiple recipients, it seems?

What would you recommend is the best approach around this? It seems very confusing and frustrating that one has to go to such lengths to get around development limitations when coding an email utility.

I am thinking of simply using the SingleEmailMessage class, sending to 1 contact only, and then having (crazy as it sounds) an Outlook forward rule that auto-forwards to a group of additional recipients. Or, i'll have to create a contact with the email address being a distribution list with multiple emails on it. I know this isn't best practice but there doesn't seem much of an alternative?